# Access functions of other classes in SlimPHP

Tags: php, oop, slim, slim-3

I have to different classes in my *Slim PHP* framework, named `OrderController` & `AddressController`. I want to access some function of `AddressController` inside `OrderController` to reduce code redundancy.

But can't get a way to do it, I got how to do it in pure PHP setup, but how to do it in *Slim PHP* framework?

**The PHP way to do this is as follows:**

```
class A {
    private $xxx;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->xxx = 'Hello';
    }

    public function getXXX() {
        return $this->xxx;
    }
}

class B {
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    function getXXXOfA() {
        return $this->a->getXXX();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);

$b->getXXXOfA();
```

**How to achieve this dependancy injection in Slim?**

[**Slim PHP Framework**](https://www.slimframework.com/)

Note: I am using *Slim PHP v3*

Comment: Inheritance : `class OrderController extends AddressControllerr`

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I cant do that, these classes are in no way related, extending one from another does not seems right. These are two classes on same level which can share some data.

Comment: @demonofthemist what is `xxx`?

Comment: @Philipp whatever you want :), getName, getAge, getTitle etc.

Comment: Thats not part of the AddressController - thats should belong to an Address model

Comment: Your code is working fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd024dbf73fcc99793781e789b2a2151b4acf032

Comment: @Justinas Thats not my actual code, this is an example of how you do it in php! I am working in SlimPHP, I know how to do this in pure PHP environment, can't find a way to do this in SlimPHP setup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reseach I finally manage to get a solution! Posting it here so if anyone in future might get help from it:

```
class FirstController 
{
    protected $container;
    protected $db;
    protected $view;
    protected $second;

    // constructor receives container instance
    public function __construct(\Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->second = new SecondController($container);
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->db = $this->container->db;
        $this->view = $this->container->view;
    }

    public function LocalFunction(){
        $this->second->otherFunction();
        //call the functions in other classes as above
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions come into mind:

#### -1-

You could also try to have the common functionality in a separate Trait.

#### -2-

I won't do the
new SecondController($container)
inside the constructor of the FirstController unless you need it at every controller-hit.
I like lazy loading, so it will load only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your `AddressController` and `OrderController` has same parent class, than move these methods to parent:

```
class AddressContoller extends Controller {
    public function test() {
        $this->methodFromParent();
    }
}
```

If not, create new object of that class and call method. Method **must** be *public*

```
class AddressContoller extends Controller {
    public function test() {
        $order = new OrderController();
        $order->publicMethodInOrderClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't move methods to other class. Second solution is like what I am looking for. I've updated my question too! How to achieve this in Slim?

Comment: @demonofthemist But your example code is working. What is wrong than?
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd024dbf73fcc99793781e789b2a2151b4acf032

Answer (score 0):

If your `OrderController` wants to call a method `foo` from `AccessController`, you should think about moving `foo` somewhere else. That's an good indicator for wrong [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

There are two possibilities

1. `foo` belongs to/is relevant for *every* Controller and has something to do with controlling: Just move it to the parent class.
2. `foo` is relevant to only a few classes: Move it to the class, it belongs to. This could be an helper class, some domain model class, or something else. Maybe you have to intruduce a new class to do this.

Comment: Thanks, AddressController manages address, all adddress, single address, locations etc. so when I want use same method I want to reuse it. Even if I move it to some other class, how to get access of that class in slim working structure, so the question is same again :(

Comment: @demonofthemist Are you currently using some or mapper framework or just plain sql statements in your AddressController?

Comment: regular sql with Slim's default $db object which use PDO for connection

Comment: see this link https://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html#add-a-database-connection